# How to do ggplot barplot in R with factor values (as y)?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart

Imagine I have the following dataframe `df` (or something along the lines of the follow table, but much longer) where I have the age group of individuals and their corresponding smoking status. The `age group` can take on values of 18-24, 24-35, and 36-50 (where the number of individuals across groups is fairly balanced) and `smoking status` is just yes or no.

```
               age-group     smoking status
 person1   |     18-24     |      yes      | 
 person2   |     25-35     |      no       |
 person3   |     36-50     |      yes      |
 person4   |     36-50     |      yes      |
 person5   |     18-24     |      no       |
 person6   |     25-35     |      no       |
 ...
```

I want to create a bar plot using `ggplot` that has the proportion that does and does not smoke for each age group (3 groups, 2 bars per group that represents proportion smoking and non-smoking). This example is tricker for me because `smoking status` is not a numerical variable but rather a factor, so I am guessing there has to be some intermediate step? As a beginner I am trying to learn a nice way to do this. I know I could do some operations through which I can compute the two proportions for each group and manually plot those values, but I want to follow nice practice.

Comment: What have you tried? The default code should work for this, since the default statistic for `geom_bar` is `stat_count` — exactly what you need here.

Comment: I have tried `p <-ggplot(df, aes(Gender, Binge))
p +geom_bar(stat = "identity")` which gives a barplot for each group but only for the 'yes' responses, not the 'no' responses. Additionally it gives the count versus proportion. Is there an option to do proportion?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility

# create a dataframe of random data
df <- data.frame(ageGroup = sample(c('18-24', '25-35', '36-50'), 50, replace = TRUE),
                 smokingStatus = sample(c('yes', 'no'), 50, replace = TRUE))

# plot it up!
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = smokingStatus)) + geom_bar() + 
    facet_wrap( ~ ageGroup, ncol = 3)
print(p)
```

Which produces:

[image: Smoking Status Histogram]